# Neo4j cypher query : using ORDER BY with COLLECT(S)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, collect

I'm having a hard time collecting data from two distinct sources and merge the collections so that the final one is a set of objects ordered by 'dateCreated'.

**Context**

Users can ask questions in groups.
A question can be either general or related to a specific video-game.
If the question asked in a group is video-game related, this question also appears in the video-game's questions page.

Currently, I have two general questions and one specific to one video-game.
Hence, when fetching the questions, I should have 3 questions.

**Query**

Here's the query :

```
START group = node(627)
MATCH generalQuestions-[?:GENERAL_QUESTION]->group
WITH group, generalQuestions
MATCH gamesQuestions-[?:GAME_QUESTION]->games<-[:GAMES]-group
WITH (collect(generalQuestions) + collect(gamesQuestions)) as questions
RETURN questions
ORDER BY questions.dateCreated
```

**First issue : using ORDER BY**

```
Cached(questions of type Collection) expected to be of type Map but it is of type Collection - maybe aggregation removed it?
```

What's the proper way of achieving what I'm trying to do?

**Second issue : wrong results**

If I remove the ORDER BY clause, instead of having 3 results, I get 14 ... :

```
[
Node[641]{dateCreated:1380892636,dateUpdated:1380892636,title:"GENERAL TITLE 1",type:1,content:"GENERAL CONTENT 1"},
Node[641]{dateCreated:1380892636,dateUpdated:1380892636,title:"GENERAL TITLE 1",type:1,content:"GENERAL CONTENT 1"},
Node[641]{dateCreated:1380892636,dateUpdated:1380892636,title:"GENERAL TITLE 1",type:1,content:"GENERAL CONTENT 1"},
Node[641]{dateCreated:1380892636,dateUpdated:1380892636,title:"GENERAL TITLE 1",type:1,content:"GENERAL CONTENT 1"},
Node[641]{dateCreated:1380892636,dateUpdated:1380892636,title:"GENERAL TITLE 1",type:1,content:"GENERAL CONTENT 1"},
Node[641]{dateCreated:1380892636,dateUpdated:1380892636,title:"GENERAL TITLE 1",type:1,content:"GENERAL CONTENT 1"},
Node[642]{dateCreated:1380892642,dateUpdated:1380892642,title:"GENERAL TITLE 2",type:1,content:"GENERAL CONTENT 2"},
Node[642]{dateCreated:1380892642,dateUpdated:1380892642,title:"GENERAL TITLE 2",type:1,content:"GENERAL CONTENT 2"},
Node[642]{dateCreated:1380892642,dateUpdated:1380892642,title:"GENERAL TITLE 2",type:1,content:"GENERAL CONTENT 2"},
Node[642]{dateCreated:1380892642,dateUpdated:1380892642,title:"GENERAL TITLE 2",type:1,content:"GENERAL CONTENT 2"},
Node[642]{dateCreated:1380892642,dateUpdated:1380892642,title:"GENERAL TITLE 2",type:1,content:"GENERAL CONTENT 2"},
Node[642]{dateCreated:1380892642,dateUpdated:1380892642,title:"GENERAL TITLE 2",type:1,content:"GENERAL CONTENT 2"},
Node[632]{dateCreated:1380889484,dateUpdated:1380889484,title:"GTA5 TITLE",type:2,content:"GTA5 CONTENT"},
Node[632]{dateCreated:1380889484,dateUpdated:1380889484,title:"GTA5 TITLE",type:2,content:"GTA5 CONTENT"}
]
```

Is there something wrong with the way I collect the results ?

**EDIT**

Expanded query to get the gamesQuestion :

```
gamesQuestions-[:GAME_QUESTION]->()<-[:QUESTIONS]-games-[:INTERESTS]->()<-[:HAS_‌​INTEREST_FOR]-interests<-[:INTERESTS]-group
```

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Order by" expects a property on a node or a relationship. The "questions" in your query is a **collection** of nodes instead of a node/relationship, you can't sort a collection using "Order by", you can only sort nodes or relationships on their properties.

In order to use "Order by", you need to return the questions as a column of rows rather than a collection. In terms of the relationships indicated in your original query, the following query should return the general and the specific game questions as a column of rows and sort them on the property "dateCreated",

```
START group = node(627) 
Match question-[?:GENERAL_QUESTION|GAME_QUESTION]->()<-[:GAMES*0..1]-(group)
Return distinct question
Order by question.dateCreated
```

For the expanded case where the game questions are related to the group via the sequence of relationships "gamesQuestions-[?:GAME_QUESTION]->games<-[:GAMES]-group, I have gamesQuestions-[:GAME_QUESTION]->()<-[:QUESTIONS]-games-[:INTERESTS]->()<-[:HAS_‌​INTEREST_FOR]-interests<-[:INTERESTS]-group", you can simply extend the pattern in the previous query as follows,

```
START group = node(627) 
Match question-[:GENERAL_QUESTION|GAME_QUESTION]->()-[*0..4]-(group)
Return distinct question
Order by question.dateCreated
```

The idea is to match the questions that can reach the group node with either one step, or 4 more steps.

Another option is to specify the two patterns in the where clause,

```
START group = node(627) 
MATCH question-[*]-group
Where question-[:GENERAL_QUESTION]->group or (question-[:GAME_QUESTION]->()<-[:QUESTIONS]-()-[:INTERESTS]->()<-[:HAS_INTERESTS_FOR]-()<-[:INTERESTS]-group)
Return distinct q
Order by q.dateCreated
```

Comment: Lisa, thanks for you answer! I understand why I could not use Order By.

But let's say for the "games questions", instead of having gamesQuestions-[?:GAME_QUESTION]->games<-[:GAMES]-group, I have gamesQuestions-[:GAME_QUESTION]->()<-[:QUESTIONS]-games-[:INTERESTS]->()<-[:HAS_INTEREST_FOR]-interests<-[:INTERESTS]-group (this time, the goal is to get all the questions of the games discussed by the group). Do you have any idea if it's possible to retrieve both the general and the game-specific questions the same way you did as a column or rows?