# Neo4j Cypher : use ORDER BY with COLLECT

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two data from two different relations (`FOLLOWS`, `LIKES`).

`FOLLOWS` relation contains `startedFollowingOn` and `LIKES` relation contains `likedOn` (both return epoch values).

What I want to achieve is sort the result on the basis of `startedFollowingOn` and `likedOn`.

```
MATCH (n1 : User {username : "abhishekm"})-[r : FOLLOWS | LIKES]-(n2) 

RETURN 
DISTINCT COLLECT ({
event : type(r),  
startedFollowingOn : r.startedFollowingOn, 
likedOn : r.likedOn})[0..10] 
AS data  LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183348/neo4j-cypher-query-using-order-by-with-collects should help you :)

Comment: @Supamiu - did you flag this as a duplicate?

Comment: @DavidMakogon no, didn't know if I should.